# ufw allow 60000:65000/tcp for FTP port 820

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ftp

I'm a bit confused, because I set up FTP server on my local host.
I used a 'vsftpd', there are two lines from my .conf file:

```
listen_port=820

ftp_data_port=821
```

And record from 'ufw'

```
To                         Action      From

--                         ------      ----

819:821/tcp                ALLOW       Anywhere 

819:821/tcp (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

---

So... everything looks ok, but when I tried to log in through browser (ftp://192.168.1.123:820), it needed a user/password, but content didn't show.

So I started with my Google journey and found out something abou FireWall and ports.

I disabled firewall - it started working
I add TCP ports range from 60000 to 65000 and it again works...

but I need to know why?

Why it is not working when my firewall is started (enabled) and tcp819,820 and 812 is allowed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With FTP the client connects to the server on the `listen_port`, i.e. `listen_port` is used as destination port for data from the client. Data transfers, i.e. directory listings and file transfers, are  done using separate TCP connections and the behavior differs between the classic active mode and the today commonly used passive mode.

In active mode the server is connecting to the client from the `ftp_data_port`. This means:  The connection gets initiated on the server side (contrary to the control connection) and `ftp_data_port` is the source port at the server side and destination port from the perspective of the client.

But since active mode does not play well with clients behind NAT (i.e. most systems at home or small office) passive mode is preferred today and most clients use it by default. In this mode not the server is connecting to the client but the client is connecting to the server. The destination port is dynamically assigned and the server tells the client in response to the `PASV` or `PORT` command which port to use. Due to how TCP works it is not enough to have a single port for all data connections to the same client and thus `ftp_data_port` will not be used for this. Instead a port in the range given by `pasv_min_port` and `pasv_max_port` will be used and if these parameters are not given an [ephemeral port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65475/ephemeral-port-what-is-it-and-what-does-it-do) will be used.